# USRP not visible in RedhawkSDR

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

I have an Ettus E312.
I want to talk with it using the RedhawkSDR IDE.
There seems to be little documentation on this. The Redhawk manual doesn't include any tutorials. It's all just guess work to the uninitiated.

I found this setup guide on the GEON website: https://geontech.com/redhawk-sdr-and-an-ettus-e310/
However, I'm having trouble getting the device to appear under the active domain in the IDE. I have flashed the SD card, and updated the domain IP address on both omniORB files (host and USRP) as per the setup guide.

Once this is working, it is still not clear how to proceed...
Could someone please point me in the right direction??

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Virtual Machine NAT was confusing things!